# How can I make hard-coded strings heinous-looking in VIM?

Tags: colors, vim

I was inspired by [this](http://secretgeek.net/6min_program.asp) (number 2) to make my hard-coded strings ugly.

How can I do this in VIM?

Comment: Just wondering; do you hate the string variable type?

Comment: @Suroot: Hard-coded strings should be avoided just as much as "magic" numbers in your source code.  Making hard-coded strings ugly just makes them stand out so you can spot them and remove them more easily.

Comment: I disagree, Bill. Hardcoded strings are sometimes bad for translation purposes but they're not as bad as magic number since they carry their definition in their content. The string "Can't open file" is every bit as good as ERR_CANNOT_OPEN_FILE.

Comment: And even for international programs, it's only necessary to translate those strings the user is expected to see. No point doing it for log messages which will only be viewed by the (e.g., English-speaking) developers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The language-based files are stored in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax`, one `.vim` file per language, so that's where you need to go to change things.

For example, my C file is stored in `C:\Program Files\Vim\vim70\syntax\c.vim` and, if you add the following line near the end, before the `let b:current_syntax = "c"`, you'll get the exact effect you require:

```
hi String guifg=#ff0000 guibg=#ffff00
```

For text-based VIM, the ctermfg and ctermbg options need to be used instead, something like:

```
hi String ctermfg=Red ctermbg=Yellow
```

I haven't tested these since I only use gvim nowadays.

Answer (score 5):

In your .vimrc:

```
highlight String guifg=1 guibg=11
```

Comment: hm... this might be setup dependant. that doesn't work for me. You may have given me enough to hunt and peck my way through it though. Thanks!

Comment: That assumes gvim.  For the command-line version, use ctermfg and ctermbg.  Plus, you need to tuen syntax highlighting on.

Comment: whew! that's heinous! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
highlight clear String
highlight link String Error
```

A bit over the top IMO, so you might want to not make it permanent.